# Can't set only 2 filter options on kendo grid

Tags: jquery, telerik, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Note: I use only the javascripts widgets of kendo, no mvc wrappers. Data is taken from html table:

```
 $("#grid1").kendoGrid({
```

I only need 2 filter options to perform row filtering: *starts with* and *contains*, but If I delete all the others and keep only those 2 the *starts with* does not work. I found out that it must be at least 3 filters declared in the js code.

```
            operators: {
            //filter menu for "string" type columns
            string: {
                //eq: "Equal:",
                startswith: "Starts with:",
                contains: "Contains:"
            }
```

I wonder whether is a bug or something wrongly declared in my code. I didn't manage to set only one filter option, whatever it is.

Comment: Hi a_maar - I just set up a sample using the demo code from http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/filter-menu-customization.html and I was able to use 1, 2 or 3 custom filter labels with no issues. Are you getting an error? or is it just not showing up correctly? or ?

Comment: Yes, no error but filter does not work, it emptys my table. Moreover I had to put the *equals* filter the first because if don't, the *starts with* didn't work well.

Comment: hmm... very strange. can you post a JSFiddle or JSBin that re-recreates the issue?

Answer (score 1):

After a bit more digging around, this appears to be a bug in older versions of Kendo.

Using the same filtering set up that you supplied:

```
    operators: {
            //filter menu for "string" type columns
            string: {
                //eq: "Equal:",
                startswith: "Starts with:",
                contains: "Contains:"
            }
```

I've put together a JSFiddle that clearly demonstrates the problem that you are having, here: http://jsfiddle.net/derickbailey/dFZhL/ - this version is running a slightly older version of Kendo.

I've put together another version of that fiddle using the most recent Kendo release, here: http://jsfiddle.net/derickbailey/amUme/ - and the filtering is working as expected.

I'm seeing a few filter related items in the release notes for Kendo as well: http://www.kendoui.com/web/whats-new/release-notes/q3-2012-sp1-version-2012-3-1315.aspx

If you're using an older version of Kendo, can you upgrade to the latest release and see if that fixes the problem?